# BIRT Grid Expansion:How to make Table grid lines static (extend to end of page) while the data in the table is dynamic?

Tags: forms, birt, dynamic-data

[image: Current Output-Grid lines end at end of data]

Overflow text of data field:
I am working on a form where the text overflow causes the grid/table/list to expand and if overflow text happens to end in the middle of the page then that is where the grid/table/list with border line (box/square) ends.  I want the grid/table/list with border line (box/square) to end consistently at the end of the page regardless of where the text ends.

The grid has column lines also,and in the first page of the form has 2 parts,the header stud below the master page header and the gird,that may expand to multiple pages after page 1.

I have been mostly developing forms using the drag-and-drop design palette.

[image: Expected Output-Grid Lines end at End of Page]

Comment: Hi! You should read through how to ask a good question and edit your question with some source code of what you have tried and what isn't working. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi,I have made some edits. I am using the Design Palette and thus do not have any code to showcase. Could you please have a look at it again and let me know.Thanks!